# Usernames cannot be changed?

Tags: feature-request, support, blog

The e-mails which I'm receiving from blog are like:

> Howdy 22370,

I've checked at my profile at: http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/wp-admin/profile.php and it reads:

> Username: 22370; Usernames cannot be changed.

but the field is disabled.

Is there any reason why users cannot change their username? Or are there any plans implementing this change?

Comment: This might be more suitable for [meta.se].

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257134/191655).